# Drupal 7 site URL is not found

Tags: php, drupal-7

I downloaded all source code from server and i would like to configure it in my local system but whenever i tried to call admin login it's given me error `The requested URL is not found` .

I also changed in `settings.php` Should anybody knows how could i resolve this error.

Thank You!

Comment: We need more information , vhosts ? settings.php ? and more..

Comment: only admin page not working or all the pages?